# How does does xrange let you test membership?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, python-2.6, xrange

Everyone seems to claim that `xrange` returns a generator but it really is its own thing:

```
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
>>> xrange(10).__bases__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'xrange' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

What I don't understand is how `xrange` lets you check membership.

```
>>> a = xrange(10)
>>> 4 in a
True
>>> 4 in a
True
```

If this was a real generator, the second check would fail since we have already iterated through the 4.

```
>>> def mygen():
...     num = 0
...     while num < 100:
...             yield num
...             num += 1
...
>>>
>>> mygen()
<generator object mygen at 0x100618b40>
>>> list(mygen())
[0, ..., 99]
>>> x = mygen()
>>> 4 in x
True
>>> 4 in x
False
```

There seems to be something special about `xrange` that lets it do membership properly, as if it overrides `__contains__`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, `xrange` is indeed not a true `<type 'generator'>`.

At the [cython level](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L338) there is a generator that powers the range logic, but there is also a `range_contains_long` function which does the comparison, bypassing iteration of the generator.

Therefore, to call `xrange` a `generator` is slightly misleading.

Comment: Indeed, `xrange` is simply another type, like `generator`, that is an iterable (because it defines an `__iter__` method).

Comment: A generator is not a specific class, it's just a set of defined behavior.  That doesn't mean the object can't have other behaviors above and beyond the generator requirements. Calling `xrange` a generator is definitely *not* misleading.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition of a generator but I see generator as `<type 'generator'>` which would not let you do this membership check. The origin of this question is that for the longest time I avoided `xrange` for membership checks under the incorrect assumption that it would fail like a generator type.